# How to add a paragraph above a bookmark using open xml?

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

I found the solution here is the code that works to add a paragraph below the bookmark using openxml.Below is the code that works:

```
   var mainPart = wDoc.MainDocumentPart;

                        var res = from bm in mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<BookmarkStart>()
                                  where bm.Name == "vendos_tekstin"
                                  select bm;
                        var bookmark = res.SingleOrDefault();
                        if (bookmark != null)
                        {
                            var parent = bookmark.Parent;   // bookmark's parent element

                            // build paragraph piece by piece
                            Text text = new Text(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " , ");
                            Text text1 = new Text(gjenerimi + " , ");
                            Text text2 = new Text(merreshifren());
                            var run = new Run();
                            run.Append(text,text1,text2);
                            Paragraph newParagraph = new Paragraph(run);
                            run.PrependChild<RunProperties>(runProp);
                            // insert after bookmark parent
                            parent.InsertAfterSelf(newParagraph);
```

Comment: Arbenita, People have been editing your question to say that the code you posted in YOUR second edit does not work. Have you solved your problem? I understood you had...

Comment: No I didn't solve my problem yet.I am trying to solve it.Thank you!

Comment: Did you try `parent.InsertBeforeSelf`? Bookmarks can be very tricky - so much depends on exactly where they're located in relation to the entire document. You may need to look in this document's Open XML (using the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool) to see where it is, relative to content preceding. This isn't something we can test for you since we dont' have that information.